# New SD card and won't let me transfer apps

Tags: samsung

Bought a new **SD card** to use on my **Samsung Galaxy Emerge** and formatted it. I was able to transfer videos and music and I have 28GB free storage left  but when I try to transfer apps it comes up as not enough room. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Provide screenshots.

Comment: I assume you mean "install apps" not "transfer apps". In this case the SD-Card is of little to no use as apps are not installed to the sd-card. See [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) wiki.

Answer (score -1):

The apps can only be accessed on the device that SD card was in when apps were saved onto card.

Comment: Not so. One can access that specific "hidden folder" on any Linux machine that can mount the card. So if you want to switch to a new card, simply switch off the device, take out the card, use a Linux machine to copy all contents to the new card, put that new card into the device, boot it up again. The only possible hinderance (except from a broken card) would be if you encrypted the card – no idea if that would work then.